# How to provide a document for the message formats an activemq instance requires to communicate with?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, swagger, activemq-classic, swagger-ui

I am trying to provide some services over ActiveMQ using Camel routing features. But I need my clients to know what kind of messages they can send over the ActiveMQ. I am thinking of something like swagger documentation for Spring MVC rest APIs. Is there any mechanism for that or I should do it manually?

Comment: Check out [AsyncAPI](https://asyncapi.org/)

Comment: Thank you so much @Helen. This is what I needed. But I have a question. Is there any other API specification similar to AsyncAPI for async services? I just want to choose the best of them.

Comment: I only know about AsyncAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen)'s comment I found out about [AsyncAPI](https://asyncapi.org/). It provides documentation and code generation tools for services provided over event-driven architectures. It is based on OpenAPI specifications like [Swagger](https://swagger.io/specification/). As stated in AsyncAPI [specifications V2.1.0](https://asyncapi.org/docs/specifications/v2.1.0):

> The AsyncAPI Specification is a project used to describe and document message-driven APIs in a machine-readable format. It’s protocol-agnostic, so you can use it for APIs that work over any protocol (e.g., AMQP, MQTT, WebSockets, Kafka, STOMP, HTTP, Mercure, etc).
>
> The AsyncAPI Specification defines a set of files required to describe such an API. These files can then be used to create utilities, such as documentation, integration and/or testing tools.

You just have to create a YAML or JSON file. They provide multiple [generators](https://www.asyncapi.com/generator) that generate codes and documents using your specification files. I used their [HTML generators](https://github.com/asyncapi/html-template) to generate my documents.

Also, [this](https://www.asyncapi.com/blog/understanding-asyncapis#the-event-driven-use-case) is a good example of how to define your specifications based on AsyncAPI.

Comment: Based on this answer I can see now what your question was actually asking. This answer is not related to the "standards" (i.e. protocols) which ActiveMQ supports (which is what it appears the question is about). This answer is about documenting the *message format* required to communicate between applications which in this case is protocol agnostic. Unfortunately the wording of your question was ambiguous and misled me.

Comment: @JustinBertram thank you for your comment. You are right. I edited the question based on your comment.

Comment: The question is closed now anyway to the point is essentially moot. Aside from eliciting opinion-based answers, it is asking software recommendations which is specifically off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes, it is closed because of that downvote. I changed the title based on your comment and I hope it gets its vote back up and gets opened again. Maybe you could give me some hints to edit the question!

Comment: The question is fundamentally opinion-based. I don't think it could be modified sufficiently short of being completely rewritten into a different question.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't really the way messaging works. ActiveMQ is a message *broker*. Each protocol which the broker supports can have client implementations in essentially any language on any platform and each such client implementation would have it's own API documentation.

ActiveMQ does provide a JMS client implementation as that is expected for JMS providers. You can read [JMS 1.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=914) specification or peruse [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/package-summary.html) in order to understand the API better.

Aside from that, ActiveMQ supports the following protocols:

- [AMQP 1.0](https://www.amqp.org/)
- [STOMP 1.0, 1.1, & 1.2](https://stomp.github.io/)
- [MQTT 3.1](https://mqtt.org/mqtt-specification/)

Again, each of these protocols will have various client implementations with their own documentation.

These protocols would be akin to HTTP in your REST use-case. They are essentially a transport mechanism. You will have to specify message formats in order to exchange data between applications. These message formats will be akin your REST API.